# Resize LVM volume with Ansible

Tags: lvm, ansible, automation

Short version: how do you resize/extend a logical volume with ansible?

It includes built-in support for managing both [physical volumes and volume groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/lvg_module.html) and [logical volumes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/lvol_module.html).

Based on the following info from that second link, I'm assuming it's capable of extending logical volumes:

1. "This module creates, removes or resizes logical volumes."
2. resizefs: Resize the underlying filesystem together with the logical volume.

Plus, the following example in the documentation:

```
- name: Extend the logical volume to take all remaining space of the PVs and resize the underlying filesystem
  lvol:
    vg: firefly
    lv: test
    size: 100%PVS
    resizefs: true
```

However, my attempts to resize result in failure.  I have these vars defined:

```
lvm_group: vg00

lvm_volumes:
  - name: /dev/mapper/vg00-lv_home
    size: 5G
```

and I'm running this task:

```
- name: configure LVM logical volumes
  lvol:
    vg: "{{ lvm_group }}"
    lv: "{{ item.name }}"
    size: "{{ item.size }}"
    resizefs: yes
  with_items:
   "{{ lvm_volumes }}"
```

Note: I've tried with resizefs set to both yes (as in the documentation) and true (as in the example).

However, I get this error when running:

```
failed: [169.198.54.175] (item={u'name': u'/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_home', u'size': u'5G'}) => changed=false
  ansible_loop_var: item
  err: |2-
      Logical Volume "lv_home" already exists in volume group "vg00"
  item:
    name: /dev/mapper/vg00-lv_home
    size: 5G
  msg: Creating logical volume '/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_home' failed
  rc: 5
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?  Am I missing some other required argument perhaps?

I'm using Ansible 2.9.10.  Thanks.

Comment: Please show the actual tasks you tried to run along with the items you passed to it.

Comment: I did.  See the vars and task I included as code, which you'll note also matches the variables mentioned in the example output.  If you're looking for something different, would you please be more specific?

Comment: Oh  you're right, not sure how I missed those. I think including the example is confusing.

Comment: I suspect you've found a subtle issue in this Ansible module. Try passing it the LV name that it wants, rather than the full path to the block device.

Comment: man, yes!  That did it.  I didn't think to try that because lvdisplay demands the full path.  But yep, just specifying the name did the trick.  Would you mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Ansible `lvol` module wants just the logical volume name as `lv`, but you have passed it the full path to the block device.  Try passing it the LV name instead.